# Проблема с массивом char c++

Tags: c++

[image: ``]

Не могу получить 0 элемент массива

Comment: закроется imgur и не будет здесь картинки. Почему бы не добавить код в непосредственно здесь?

Comment: SO использует imgur как платформу по умолчанию для всех загруженных картинок) Так что проблема не в ненадёжности сервиса imgur, а в неудобстве гадания по фотографии)

Answer (score 5):

потому что через `""` - задаются строки, по сути это указатели в память, а вы сравниваете с `char` - однобайтовой буквой

буквы (символы) задаются через `''`

правильно так:

```
gotten_word[0] == 'A'
```

Кроме того `char` - это так же может интерпретироваться как целочисленное значение от -128 до 127, поэтому компилятор и ругнулся на то, что вы сравниваете между указателем ("A") и числом (`char` - `gotten_word[0]`)

Comment: Ох, 10к не за горами =)

Comment: @vp_arth yup ;D